# Effective way to organize views script in web app

Tags: php, zend-framework, web-applications, model-view-controller

I'm developing an web project(in PHP with Zend1, but I think it will not really be so important).

In this project, we have many user, have many role, and each role as you may know can do stuffs of thing, not so complicated(there are about 4,5 role and we have about 20 view script page).

It sounds no thing special, sure. In the controller, I have implemented something like ACL, it checks permission each user action and dispatch...

But I'm getting stuck on how to organize or generate view for each role, are there any way to effectively solve it. Can you show me how you did, to solve this kind of problem.

For now, my view script was so complicated and you must be crazy to maintain it.

```
// in user/update.phtml
<? if($this -> currentUser -> isAdmin) { ?>
      html view for admin, such as show update, delete link
<?} else {?>
      html for other
<?}?>
// note that this kind of code appear randomly and quite usually
```

Many thanks

Comment: Go through the Zend Framework ACL Documentation thoroughly,  Sure you will find the best way to do that in it .

Comment: Why not use different layouts for each role and then include view scripts specific to roles within the layout?